# Objects being moved with each other inside an area

Tags: transforms, shortcut

I have accidentally enabled a mode which creates a kind of smooth brush whenever I move an object. And when I drag it across the axis everything inside the circle gets moved as well. How do I stop this and what is the keyboard shortcut?

[image: http://imgur.com/2SOAJpx,e4Q267b#0] - This is the difference in the tool bar, in other .blends without the problem there is no (Smooth).

[image: http://imgur.com/2SOAJpx,e4Q267b#1] - This is the circle in which everything in it also gets moved, this can be re sized but not removed. And even if I re size it until it is almost gone, it still creates problems.

If someone could help me figure out this problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is called proportional editing and is enabled by pressing O.

Answer (score 1):

Available Shortcuts for Proportional Edit tool:

1. <kbd>O</kbd> to enable/disable Regular mode;
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to enable/disable Connected mode;
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to switch among the Falloff types.